# How to stick char array with strcat MATLAB

Tags: matlab

This is the question:

I have the next 3 variables:

```
A=['a1';'a2';'a3']';
B=['b1';'b2';'b3']';
C=['c1';'c2';'c3']';
```

And I want to stick all of them with an strcat, and if a do this:

```
D=strcat('',A,'-',B,'-',C,'')

D =

a1-b1-c1
a2-b2-c2
a3-b3-c3
```

But if I want to make an space, like this:

```
D=strcat(['',A,'   -   ',B,'   -   ',C,''])
```

I got this error:

**CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.**

Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: Really thanks to that one who gave to me a negative point, can you please explain my error and I offer my apologies for my ignorance, thank you.

Comment: Perhaps they think the question is too basic. Truth is, all you need to know about this is in `help strcat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the brackets. Remove them. Also, you don't need those empty strings:

```
>> strcat(A, '   -   ', B, '   -   ', C)
ans =
    a1   -b1   -c1
    a2   -b2   -c2
    a3   -b3   -c3
```

Note that trailing spaces are removed by `strcat`.  To prevent that from happening, use cells; but then the result will be a cell array of strings, not a 2D char array:

```
>> strcat(A, {'   -   '}, B, {'   -   '}, C)
ans = 
    'a1   -   b1   -   c1'
    'a2   -   b2   -   c2'
    'a3   -   b3   -   c3'
```

To obtain a 2D char array, use horizontal concatenation. You'll need `repmat` to make the number of rows match:

```
>> [ A, repmat('   -   ',size(A,1),1), B, repmat('   -   ',size(A,1),1), C ]
ans =
    a1   -   b1   -   c1
    a2   -   b2   -   c2
    a3   -   b3   -   c3
```